# Unsure how the following summation simplifies down to this known result?

Tags: summation

How does this:

$$\frac{1}{c+1} + (c-1)\cdot\left(\frac{1}{c(c+2)}+\dotsb+\frac{1}{(n-2)n}\right) + \left(\frac{c-1}{n-1}\right)\cdot\frac{1}{2}$$

Become this:

$$= \frac{2cn-c^2+c-n}{cn}$$

PS. $1 \leq c \leq n$. Not sure if that's needed or not.

Edit:

Am I right with:

$$\frac{1}{c+1} + (c-1)[\frac{1}{c} + \frac{1}{c+1} - \frac{1}{n-1} - \frac{1}{n}] + \frac{c-1}{2(n-1)}$$

When I sub numbers in for $c$ and $n$, this does not seem to give me the above final line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

$$
\frac{1}{k(k+1)} = \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1}
$$
and the entire bracket is a telescoping series

**UPDATE**
Your case is
$$
\frac{1}{k(k+2)}
 = \frac{1}{2} \left[\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+2}\right]
$$

After you apply this, you get
$$
\begin{split}
S &= \sum_{k=c}^{n-2}\frac{1}{k(k+2)}
   = \frac12 
     \sum_{k=c}^{n-2}\left[\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+2}\right]\\
  &= \frac12 \left[ \sum_{k=c}^{n-2} \frac{1}{k}
                  - \sum_{k=c+2}^n \frac{1}{k} \right] \\
  &= \frac12 \left[ \frac1c + \frac{1}{c+1}
                   -\frac1{n-1} - \frac{1}n\right]
\end{split}
$$
Hence
$$
\begin{split}
V &= \frac{1}{c+1}
   + (c-1)\sum_{k=c}^{n-2}\frac{1}{k(k+2)}
   + \left(\frac{c-1}{n-1}\right)\cdot\frac{1}{2} \\
  &= \frac{1}{c+1}
   + \frac{c-1}{2}
     \left[ \frac1c + \frac{1}{c+1}
                   -\frac1{n-1} - \frac{1}n\right]
   + \left(\frac{c-1}{n-1}\right)\cdot\frac{1}{2} \\
  &= \frac{1}{c+1}
   + \frac{c-1}{2}
     \left[ \frac1c + \frac{1}{c+1} - \frac{1}n\right]\\
\end{split}
$$
Could you now complete this?

Comment: Thanks. I've used this to simplify it, but I seem to have made a mistake? It doesn't seem to match up with the final line.

Comment: @Penguin47 please see the update

Comment: Thank you. I see my mistake now.